Where to check Safari Web Extension's storage data
I have a Safari web extension converted from Chrome extension, I am trying to find where local storage data is saved and how can we view or retrieve it using JS code.
I am trying to save data to local storage in Safari browser using the below code,
chrome.storage.sync.set({'inputFieldName': inputFieldName,})
but not able to find in storage tab in inspect element area.
I have also tried below code, but no luck.
browser.storage.local.set({'inputFieldName': inputFieldName,})
Can anyone help me how to find this data I am storing?

use localStorage and the message system between the background  and content script. It seems the injected content script cannot directly access the local storage of its own extension.
request message:
browser.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "requestData" }).then(handleResponse, handleError);

reponse:
 browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === "requestData") {
       
        localStorage.getItem(key, function (data) {
           
            sendResponse(data); //send back to the sender
        });
    }
    return true; 
});

access the local storage:
localStorage.getItem(key);
localStorage.setItem(key, value);

Thanks Kyle! Also in Safari extension, sendResponse(data) will not work, we'll need to send message from background.js to the script after getting data from localStorage.getItem method.
